# how to add 2 javascript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, actions-on-google

I am working on a project on actions on Google where I have an index.js file. It is getting large (I have a lot of functions in it) so I want to distribute it into multiple javaScript file. Perhaps something like index.js, index2.js, and index3.js. How can I add the functions I declare in index2.js and index3.js to my index.js.

*I am not using HTML file, it is for Actions on Google using node.js*

and I am not making any module

Comment: it wont be a easy task unless properly designed

Comment: read through this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at how node.js lets you `require` additional code. You can't just import an entire file (or at least you shouldn't), but you can use this to break up your code into more discrete chunks, and then have your top level `index.js` require the functions you need, by name if you wish.

One approach (not necessarily the best, but it should work) is to do something like this.

Your `functions.js` file might look something like this:

```
exports.func1 = function(){
  // Do stuff
};

exports.func2 = function(parameters){
  // Do other stuff
}
```

and your `index.js` might now have

```
const F = require('./functions');

F.func1();

F.func2( 'whee!' );
```

If you dislike the `F.` part so much, you could even do something like

```
const func1 = require('./functions').func1;
const func2 = require('./functions').func2;

func1();

func2( 'whee!' );
```

or even something like

```
const {func1, func2} = require('./functions');

func1();

func2( 'whee!' );
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this might help me

Comment: If an answer helps, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.

Comment: just figuring out how to accept this answer

Comment: You should be able to accept an answer by clicking on the checkbox under the up and down arrows to the left of the answer. You can upvote it by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer.

Comment: couldn't vote because of some StackOverflow policy , but yes accepted this answer